# Copying files form directory to another

Tags: ssh

I have the following structure on my server:

/www/html/www->content

I want to copy the content (all files) from the last www to html and delete the second www after that.  How do I have to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cp /www/html/www/* /www/html/
```

then

```
sudo rm -r /www/html/www
```

Comment: I am getting an error, if I sue the command. the error says, that the file or directoty could noz be found. I Used thsi command:

Comment: sudo cp /www/html/www/* /www/html/

Answer (score 0):

In sh:

```
mv /www/html/www/* /www/html/ && rmdir /www/html/www
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `rsync`:

```
sudo rsync -avz /www/html/www/ /www/html/
```

It's what I use to create backups. It syncs files on copy when copying across different hard drives, `-a` takes care about file access rights and ownership. When copying across servers, `-z` uses compression.

After that, delete the dir:

```
sudo rm -f /www/html/www
```